# using vectors to make generic stacks

Tags: c++, templates

So I am trying to define a stack class, which then uses vectors to make a generic stack. For some reason when I try to create a new stack I receive an error saying nothing was was declared, I understand this as it saying that nothing was essentially made, I was never actually made a new object. I did follow this guide on how to make generic stacks.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

here is the Stack class that I used:

```
#ifndef stackers
#define stackers
#include <vector>

#include "Wrapper.hh"

template <class T>
class Stack { 
  private: 
    vector<T*> elems;
  public: 
    Stack();
    void push(T* obj);  // push element 
    T* pop();
    T* peek();           // pop element 
    T* findMax();
    T* findMin();
    bool isEmpty();
}; 
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>:: isEmpty(){
    return elems.size()==0;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push (T* obj) 
{ 
    // append copy of passed element 
    elems.push_back(obj);    
} 
template <class T>
T* Stack<T>::peek () 
{ 
    // append copy of passed element 
    elems.at(elems.size());    
} 

template <class T>
T* Stack<T>::pop () 
{ 
    if (elems.empty()) { 
        fatal("Stack<>::pop(): empty stack"); 
    }
    // remove last element 
    return elems.pop_back();         
} 

template<class T>
T* Stack<T>:: findMax(){
    T* temp=new T*;
    for(int i=0;i<elems.size();i++){
        if(elems.at(i)>temp)
            temp=elems.at(i);
    }
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
T* Stack<T>:: findMin(){
    T* temp;
    for(int i=0;i<elems.size();i++){
        if(elems.at(i)<temp)
            temp=elems.at(i);
    }
    return temp;
}
#endif
```

When I call this in my main:

```
      Stack<Pictures> stackers;
```

Where picture is an object I have made in another class.
It throws the error, "error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]". I assumed I didn't need a constructor due to the example that I was following. Is that not the case for non-primative data types?

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: The line in my main, where I try to initialize a new Stack of type Picture.

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: "Main.cc:32:7: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you say

```
#define stackers
```

at the very top of your header,

```
Stack<Pictures> stackers;
```

becomes

```
Stack<Pictures> ;
```

...which does indeed not declare anything.

Comment: I didn't realize that I couldn't name it something I defined in a header file. Thanks!

Comment: You can, sort of (although it's arguably never a good idea). Macros (`#define`d stuff) are expanded before the code goes to the compiler, and they're simply text replacements. If you say `#define foo bar` and declare `int foo;`, the compiler will see `int bar;` -- which works. In this case, however, `stackers` is defined as nothing, so it is replaced with nothing, and that doesn't work because the compiler expects something in its place.

Comment: I took care of that error, and now when I do name it something else I receive this error. "Main.cc:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `Stack<Pictures>::Stack()'"

Comment: You forgot to implement `Stack`'s constructor.

Comment: Basing off of the example that I linked I was under the improper assumption that I didn't have to. Thank you for being helpful and I wish I could upvote you!

Comment: The error was because I had defined the constructor in prototype but never implemented it.